# JPA persist generic entity

Tags: apache, hibernate, jpa, apache-poi, persistent

I need some helps with JPA 2.1 (and ORM Hibernate).

I have some entity (3-4) mapped in database table, and I can see their rows into separate primefaces datatable. I also export these data in .xls file with apache poi.
Everything works perfectly.

Now, I need to import and read an excel file (I already done it), and insert the new information in a table.

Can I implement a generic JPA method to insert (make persistent) a series of data?

Something like this

```
EntityManager em = getEntityManager;
em.getTransaction().begin();

Employee employee = new Employee();
employee.setFirstName("Bob");
....

em.persist(employee);
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

But with "generic" and not specific entity (in this case is "Employee"), so as to create an unique persistent method for all entities, and not several specific method for each entity? (Whereas they also have different names of columns).

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

You need a way to determine the following:

- What entity type should the excel row be implied as.
- What is the property mappings between the various excel columns and the entity properties.

With those pieces of information, you could easily use a no-arg constructor for each of you entity classes to construct a new instance, use a library like BeanUtils or equivalent to set the property values based on your column to property mappings and then persist it.

From a JPA persistence perspective, there is absolutely nothing here that affects that.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.
For the first point I have a way to identify the entity on which to load the data, based on the panel's id which I import the excel. 
For the second point I have to think more...

I've heard of that library, now i will look more